# Create a instance of a C++ class within a blueprint

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

I'd like to create an instance of a C++ class in a blueprint.
That's my current approach, but the instance is *None*. Why?

[image: blueprint example]

Answer (score 1):

I'd tried to get the class by an instance which is not instantiated.

Fix:

[image: fixed]

Comment: While this certainly would work, I'm wondering why you're setting this action every tick.  Does it need to happen that often?

Comment: Hey @Stephen, i do my first steps here and wanna see if i have some memory leaks or some other behavior before i go on. Thx for starting this conversation.

Comment: Not a problem.  If this were me, I'd run the Construct Action at Begin Play and set Action there.  This will then be available to later items in your tick method without it having to be set every time.